# I cannot seem to add subtitles to MP4 using FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video, mp4, subtitles, totem

I have a video called **test_video.mp4** downloaded from YouTube

[image]

This is the information of the video obtained by running `ffmpeg -i test_video.mp4`:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'test_video.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.19.102
  Duration: 00:00:17.62, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 265 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 138 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc.
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc.
```

I have also a file with subtitles called **test_sub.srt**:

```
1
00:00:01,000 --> 00:00:05,000
Hello

2
00:00:10,000 --> 00:00:15,000
World
```

When I run `ffmpeg -i test_video.mp4 -i test_sub.srt -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 1:0 -c:v copy -c:a copy -c:s mov_text -metadata:s:s:0 language=eng test_out.mp4`, soft subtitles are added:

[image]

The problem comes when I try to do the same to a bigger video called **test2_video.mp4**, I run `ffmpeg -i test2_video.mp4 -i test_sub.srt -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 1:0 -c:v copy -c:a copy -c:s mov_text -metadata:s:s:0 language=eng test2_out.mp4` but subtitles are not added to **test2_out.mp4**. This is the information of the video when I run `ffmpeg -i test2_video.mp4`:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'test2_video.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
  Duration: 00:59:11.08, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2131 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1997 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

Why does this happen?, the version of **FFmpeg** that I'm running is **4.2.7-0ubuntu0.1**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, the problem is not **FFmpeg**, the problem is my default media player: **Totem Media Player**. For an unknown reason, Totem doesn't show you the subtitles if they're too short in time in comparison with the length of the video, if another sequential subtitle is added to **test_sub.srt**, but at least until 00:11:51,000 (in this particular example), the subtitles are displayed

```
1
00:00:01,000 --> 00:00:05,000
Hello

2
00:00:10,000 --> 00:00:15,000
World

3
00:11:50,000 --> 00:11:51,000
.
```

I know the problem is Totem because I decided to try other media players like **VLC** and this problem doesn't exist